# Inherit() в javascript

Tags: javascript

Вот есть такой код:

```
 var q = {v:1, s:5};
var p = {};
p = inherit(q);
alert(p);
```

Я так понял, что функцией inherit  я говорю объекту p, что нужно наследовать свойства q.v и q.s - ведь так? Почему эта строка так упорно выдаёт ошибку?
Я так понял, inherit просто наследут свойства, разве нет?

```
Страница 145 - Жэвид флэнаган. JS подробное руководство 6-е издание.
var o = {} // o наследует методы объекта Object.prototype
o.x = 1; // и обладает собственным свойством x.
var p = inherit(o); // p наследует свойства объектов o и Object.prototype
p.y = 2; // и обладает собственным свойством y.
var q = inherit(p); // q наследует свойства объектов p, o и Object.prototype
q.z = 3; // и обладает собственным свойством z.
var s = q.toString(); // toString наследуетсяот Object.prototype
q.x + q.y // => 3: x и y наследуются от o и p
```

Comment: Может потому, что в js нет built-in функции inherit? Если вы про какую-то библиотеку, то неплохо бы ее название указать. Ну и текст ошибки привести надо бы.

Comment: Если вам нужен [inherit][1], возьмите и добавьте функцию для него :)

  [1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/prototype#эмуляция-object-create-для-ie8

Comment: @MasterAlex, 
Вот у них тоже пример:

    var animal = { eats: true };
    var rabbit = inherit(animal);
    alert(rabbit.eats);

Тестирую в консоли хрома, тоже не отрабатывает.

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, а давно у нас в консоль хрома функцию inherit добавили? [Смотрим в консоль][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/75g4hurw/

Comment: А по поводу Дэвида Флэнагана, смотрите страницу 141 внизу, там, где он создаёт функцию inherit().

Comment: @MasterAlex спасибо, т.е. из встроенных ф-ций я могу использовать _proto_ для наследования?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, вывод неверен, читайте документацию подробно по ссылке

Comment: @MasterAlex А какой вывод я должен сделать? Я прочитал learn.javascript.ru  про цепочки наследования и т.д., но вот какой вывод должен сделать, не совсем понимаю...

Comment: Я так понял, за наследование отвечает slice(), но по ссылке там ни слова о ней.

Answer (score 1):

В js нет такой функции, как inherit, функция inherit это fallback для Object.create:

```
var o = {} // o наследует методы объекта Object.prototype
    o.x = 1; // и обладает собственным свойством x.
    var p = Object.create(o); // p наследует свойства объектов o и Object.prototype
    p.y = 2; // и обладает собственным свойством y.
    var q = Object.create(p); // q наследует свойства объектов p, o и Object.prototype
    q.z = 3; // и обладает собственным свойством z.
    var s = q.toString(); // toString наследуетсяот Object.prototype
    q.x + q.y // => 3: x и y наследуются от o и p
    console.log( q.__proto__ ); // смотрим прототип
```

Вот так можно реализовать inherit:

```
function inherit( obj ) {
 function F () {};
 F.prototype = obj;
 return new F();
}
```