# Не понимаю работу функции inherit()?

Tags: javascript

Зачем нужен `фиктивный конструктор`:

```js
function f(){};
```

И что мы делаем строкой:

```js
f.prototype = p;
```

```js
// Девид Фленаган 2013
function inherit(p) {
    if (p == null) throw TypeError();
    if (Object.create) return Object.create(p);
    var t = typeof p;
    if ( t !== "Object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
    function f(){};
    f.prototype = p;
    return new f();
}
```

К сожалению, для меня, далее он (автор книги) постоянно использует данную функцию. Не понимая её не могу двигаться дальше.

Вопрос в дополнение к [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393263/inherit-%D0%B2-javascript).

Comment: в данном случае мы проверяем что переданный параметр  p является функцией if ( t !== "Object" && t !== "function") если это правда то мы добавим ее в prototype созданного конструктора  function f(){};
    f.prototype = p;
     то есть унаследуем ее в новом конструкторе ну или скопируем его туда ... если вам так будет легче понимать + его return:  return new f(); ...

Comment: Все это он пытается вначале сделать по проще в одну строку  if (Object.create) return Object.create(p); + всегда при недостижимости цели он выбрасывает throw TypeError() я старался изложить максимально просто.

Comment: @sair Я всё равно не понял, зачем нужен фиктивный конструктор? Если `p` и так функция? И поясните пожалуйста сто делает строка `f.prototype = p;` более подробно.

Comment: мои извинения,  точнее проверка что это не объект и функция if ( t !== "Object" && t !== "function")

Comment: То есть мы хотим поместить значения типа  string или number или boolean как свойство конструктора по умолчанию,  f.prototype = p;  если  мы таким  образом создадим три одинаковых конструктора  
 new f() 
 то при изминении значения в одном не приведут к изминению в другом, они становятся независимыми копиями своего отдельного конструктора

Comment: почитайте про паттерн фабрика

Comment: По поводу prototype, это свойство есть у каждой функции, оно хранит все методы  экземпляров ссылочного типа, к примеру попробуйте в конструкторе p переопределить toString  а затем вызвать его из prototype этого конструктора p.prototype.toString()... результат будет такой же как p.toString()

Comment: И меня немного смутило f.prototype = p; обычно выставляется имя к которому мы потом сможем обратится f.prototype.p = p;